# How to secure REST API payload while in transit?

Tags: python, angularjs, rest, security, encryption

I am trying to find out ways to secure REST API communication. The following are the items considered.

- Enabled token based authentication using JWT
- Enabled HTTPS and restrict requests over HTTP

Our GUI interacts with service layer APIs which are secured as described above. All the requests from GUI contains sensitive information and hence the data has to be secured at every place.

In short, our GUI is secured with role based authentication and APIs are secured as above. Still I feel the communication between GUI and services are not secure enough.

- Is the payload from GUI secure enough? or should the payload also be encrypted from GUI itself?

If this is not the right place to ask this question, I am happy to move it to right place.

Please advice!
Thank you in advance

Comment: What kind of data is it?  Is it PII?  HIPAA?  FOUO? Classified?  Or just ordinary traffic?

Comment: Hi Robert, the data contais usernames, passwords and/or api tokens including server details to interact. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understood from the post is that your GUI is secured role based and the api is secured using token and https.

Apart from these, as I understand you app is too sensitive, in that case I would do the following to add some extra layer of security.

1. Add a two step verfication for the GUI just to ensure that right person is logged in all time.
2. Encrypt the data (i.e. the payload) may be using the public/private key.In this case the server side needs to be changed a bit as it needs to decrypt the request .
3. Make sure your token has a lifetime and expires after certain time.

Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Comment: That is what i am thinking too. REST API communication is open. Having encryption at client side and handle at server side helps. Thank you !

Comment: Please how can i use public key and private key encryption for nodejs?